# Would I be able to enter USA currently?

Tags: visas, usa, uk-citizens, long-term

Over the last 4-5 years, I've made around 6 visits to the US. Once I stayed for 1 month while subsequent visits lasted for 79-85 days each, with gaps of 1-2 months between, and from September 2013.

On my last entry, in May 2013 until August 2013, the CBP officer told me that they would not return if they were me, for 6 months, or even better, a year. However, I was not issued an entry ban. The last 5 visits have all been to Los Angeles for recreational visits, and they were all around 80 days each.

So last month, I attended the US Embassy in London to apply for a visa for recreational purposes again. I am British. As my application was for a longer visit, 1 or 2 years, they said I was ineligible for a visa, but that I could apply again. Their website does not specify the time limit they mentioned (6 months) for recreational purposes, as far as I have ever seen.

I like visiting Los Angeles. My question is, if I fly there, say this month, would I likely be allowed entry?

Comment: Within the time spent outside than inside the US rule, just.  So you're be suspicious now, after 13 months?

Comment: Are you sure it's the TSA?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you have been found ineligible for a visa. You are therefore [not allowed to use the Visa Waiver Program anymore](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visa-waiver-program.html):

> If you have had a U.S. visa before or previously traveled to the United States under the VWP or another status, you must have complied with the conditions of previous admissions to the United States, and you must not have previously been found ineligible for a U.S. visa.

So the answer would be: No, you are not allowed to enter. From now on, you need to apply for a visa for any visit to the US.

Comment: Technically this is not correct.  The rules have changed, but the websites have not been updated.  If you apply for an ESTA, declare that you have been refused a visa, and your ESTA is approved then you can visit under the VWP.  Note that this does NOT address the issue of whether he would be admitted - even if an ESTA was approved. And realistically at this point it's very unlikely an ESTA would be approved.

Comment: @Doc I didn't get into the other question because it seemed moot. But of course if the rules changed, that's another matter.

Comment: I'm not sure we understand.  The embassy gave me a letter saying that my application meant that I was "unqualified" for a visa, and it's not a refusal as far as I understand it.   As I'd  asked for longer than is usually allowed in my case, which is 6 months according to the consulate staff member.  I dont know about not not being able to use the Visa Waiver Program, as if I needed to, I'd be able to get one as far as I know.

Comment: Presuming you actually applied for a visa (as opposed to just asking about one), then the only two options are that it was approved, or that it was rejected.  Legally there is no third option.

Comment: I couldn't apply again though if I was rejected could I?  It wasn't rejected but said the application was "unqualified".  Don't know if it counts as a rejection.  Does it mean I couldn't get an ESTA or a visa?  Its confusing.

Comment: @ChristopherWright: You can always apply again if you are rejected. You can apply and get rejected each day if you want to.

Comment: @Doc and others: Maybe someone who has a good source on the new rules could provide a better answer?

Comment: @ChristopherWright I am not an expert in US law and have never been denied a visa but my understanding is that they typically use such disconcerting terminology. I though they would find you “ineligible” instead of “unqualified” so it could make a difference. Did that letter quote a specific section from the US Immigration and Nationality Act (something like 214(b) or 221(g))?

Comment: @Doc Is that so? I was trying to find out and could not really find anything definitive. In the Schengen area by contrast, there is a third solution which is to decline to accept the application (e.g. because you applied to the wrong consulate), which carries no prejudice.

Comment: Relaxed, you're right, it was 214 (b), they used.  The letter states I have " not met the legal standards to qualify" and that the "decision is final and cannot be appealed.  It says uf I decide to reapply, I "must schedule a new interview and pay a new visa application fee", so I'm slightly hoping in re-reading that, that I don't have to start all over again, although I probably do?

Comment: User 102008, seems impossible to do as you cant obtain a new decision daily.

Comment: That's why I'm asking this question anyway but really its because of the time I've spent there previously, and whether I could reenter again if I go now. That's what I need to know.

Comment: @ChristopherWright It might be best to add those details to the question and maybe someone will provide a comprehensive answer. My understanding is that you do need to reapply for something in any case (either for a visa or, according to the discussion above, for a fresh ESTA) and there is a high chance it will be rejected. You definitely shouldn't show up using your older ESTA and hope to be granted entry.

Comment: I'd be rejected for which, an ESTA, or a visa?  If the ESTA is valid, I don't see why not?  I used 2 ESTAs during my 3 trios if 79-81 days.  I've tried detailing the whole question, but then maybe its too complex.

Comment: My guess is both but I don't really know. Until recently, you would not be eligible for VWP travel at all, *per* the website I quoted. Basically, the rules are designed to prevent doing exactly what you have been doing (effectively staying most of the time or at least a large part of the time in the US using multiple short stays). As long as you don't fall foul of some hard limit like the 90-day maximum stay, you can skirt them for some time but not forever.

Comment: @ChristopherWright Incidentally, both the warning you got on your last entry and the visa rejections are very strong signs that you have been stretching the rules and risk being flat-out denied entry if you try again. I can see how that's unpleasant if you want to return to the US soon but that's still the way it is.

Comment: Although it's been 13 months now, and not 12?

Comment: @Doc do you have a link for this rule change? It would be very useful to tell people that if they're VWP eligible wow previously been denied visas.